# Making app icon unchangable

Tags: android, icons

> Is it possible to make my application icon to be unchangable , that is in different mobile depending upon the mobile theme app icon will change into rounded and box shaped shape. Shall we make our icon irrespective to phone themes and make it at fixed shape and design to all mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

I Think it is not possible

Because theme can crop icon to round or anything else

So, you can't do anything

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `Launcher application` does.It will change your icon to some themes which they think is more pretty.

So you can do nothing with it.